# why does php shows a notice when trying to access an associative array through one of the key? is it possible to disable it for this case?

Tags: php

lets suppose the example I am using is the following

```
     $fields = array('Name','Age','Grade');

     $studentsDictionary = array(array('Name'=>'Mark','Age'=>15,'Grade'=>19),
                     array('Name'=>'John','Age'=>15,'Grade'=>11),
                     array('Name'=>'Tom','Age'=>15,'Grade'=>10));

    for($i =0;$i<sizeof($studentsDictionary);$i++)
    {
        for($j=0;$j<sizeof($fields);$j++)
        {
            echo $studentsDictionary[$j][$fields[$i]].' ';
            echo array_keys($studentsDictionary)[$j][$i].' ';
        }
        echo $nl;
    }
```

I have 2 way to access the key of the associative array one is creating an array which contains the string keys for said associative array and the other I found was using array_keys(arrayName)[index][key_index] (like using [i][j] but backwards indexing...)
so every time I use the 2nd method it shows

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\phptest\index.php on line 75

can I disable such notice for this case?

Comment: Don't try to disable notices, try and fix them!  In the second piece of code you have `[$i]` but the first line you have `[$fields[$i]]`.

Comment: keep in mind the error is the 2nd method which throws an error so why it allow such syntax?

Comment: What is your expected output here? I'm having a difficult time understanding what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @El_Vanja no notice if the syntax is valid? why would ever say you are trying to acces an offset of a value type and yet retrieve the value? either you dont show the notice because it is valid or dont show it because it is against the valid syntax I dont use dynamic weak typed languages so I dont know if this is a common mistake to me this seems unreasonable to show a notice for something is valid

Comment: What do you mean by "syntax is valid"? You're doing something wrong, `array_keys` cannot return a two-dimensional array and you're trying to access a second dimension, but I fail to understand what your code is supposed to achieve. Are both commands supposed to have same output?

Comment: @El_Vanja from what I have read it returns an array of key for said array so accessing thorugh an index should return the value without showing a notice, why would you ever give the value along with a notice? `Mark
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptest\index.php on line 75` for example it shouldnt show the  value if calling by an index in the new array of keys is totally fine? unless that whatever array_key is returning is not a string array because I have seen that it is possible to call an array key by writing the string of said key

Comment: Well, you misunderstood it. The result of your `array_keys($studentsDictionary)` call is `[0, 1, 2]`. Not the entire structure of subarrays, just the level it was called for.

Comment: Another misconception you're having here is this: "why would you ever give the value along with a notice", you're *not* getting the value. The output doesn't exist, you only got the notice.

Comment: @El_Vanja I got both but you are right the result of the array_keys is an index

Comment: An int is not an array. That's what the message says. So obviously you have a bug.

Comment: No, you didn't get both. The first echo gave you output, the second gave you the notice. Otherwise there'd be more data printed to the screen (3 x 3 = 9 after iteration, x2 echo commands gives a total of 18, you have 9 prints and 9 notices).

Comment: So i canrt retrieve the array of the keys rather their index? to return 'Name' 'Age' 'Grades'

Answer (score 0):

Notice means a bug. So better to fix the bug.

Your first method is incorrect. $i and $j should be shifted.
Second method is also incorrect. array_keys method works on associative arrays. You have applied array_keys to a normal array.

Correct code is,

```
 $fields = array('Name','Age','Grade');
 $studentsDictionary = array(array('Name'=>'Mark','Age'=>15,'Grade'=>19),
                 array('Name'=>'John','Age'=>15,'Grade'=>11),
                 array('Name'=>'Tom','Age'=>15,'Grade'=>10));

for($i =0;$i<sizeof($studentsDictionary);$i++)
{
    for($j=0;$j<sizeof($fields);$j++)
    {
        echo $studentsDictionary[$i][$fields[$j]].' ';
        echo array_keys($studentsDictionary[$i])[$j].' ';
    }
    echo $nl;
}
```